# Cannot download an image with an HttpClientBuilder object

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to download images in Java using HttpClientBuilder. On most of the cases I do not have any problem, but on this particular example, I cannot make it work and I do not know what else to try.

I attach a code example, when I run it I always get a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`.

I've tried setting a specific User-Agent, and other settings in the request with no luck.

Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient2 = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                    RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                            .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000)
                            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000)
                            .setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000)
                            .build())
            .build();

    final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URI.create("https://www.net-a-porter.com/variants/images/1647597286238991/in/w230_q80.jpg"));
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpClient2.execute(httpGet)) {
        // code never reached
    }
```

Comment: With curl it works, but I need to do it in java, see curl command -> `curl 'https://www.net-a-porter.com/variants/images/1647597286238991/in/w230_q80.jpg' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'if-modified-since: Mon, 16 Jan 2023 20:30:31 GMT' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed --output test.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the user agent to something else. For example "Safari/537.36".

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient2 = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                        .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000)
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000)
                        .setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS * 1000)
                        .build())
                .setUserAgent("Safari/537.36")
                .build();
```

It seems to be working for me with the "Safari/537.36" user agent.